# Efficient Way to Move Element Within std::deque?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, stl, c++17

I am trying to maintain a sorted list.

Hence, when the key (not unique) of en element has changed, I will need to move an element at one location in std::deque to another location within the same std::deque.

I wonder what the most efficient way is.  The simplest way is to do 1 binary search + 1 insert + 1 erase, which might involve memory allocation and deallocation.

Another way is to just call `std::sort` each time (after the key has changed) as it will do `std::swap` underneath.  But it is a bit heavy O(n log n) (vs O(1) with 1 binary search + 1 insert + 1 erase = O(log n)).

Any suggestion is welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like `std::deque` is not the appropriate container for your needs. Something like `std::set` or `std::priority_queue` or `std::list` *may* be more appropriate, depending. If you want to get useful help, you'll need to describe your actual use case.

Comment: @sneftel I am trying to use a queue to hold a list of tailor made timer tasks.  Hence, I want to keep them sorted so that I can fire them in the correct sequence.  Yes, I am aware of `timerfd` and alike.  I have a specific environment that I can't use any OS based timer.

Comment: Yes, `std::multiset` is a natural choice.  Tho, `std::map`, `std::multiset`, and `std::set` have some latency spikes when tree rebalancing happens (I measured).

Comment: That is *exactly* the most common application for a priority queue.

Comment: `std::priority_queue` doesn't seem to allow one to traverse to delete or repush an element when a timer task has been rescheduled...

Comment: No, it doesn't really. It's not a very good priority queue. Around here we use a custom priority queue structure based on a pairing heap. It's an intrusive container, for fast updates. That all may be overkill for you unless your situation is particularly performance-critical.

Answer (score 1):

First qustion I would ask myself is why to use an `std::deque` container. It's neither the best data locality nor the fastest insertions. Especially when there is a container specifically designed for maintaining the sorting order at a minimum cost — [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map).

If you need both data locality and maintained sorting order have a look at [`boost::intrusive::map`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/intrusive/map_multimap.html) and [`boost::flat_map`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/doc/html/boost/container/flat_map.html). They keep data local and just update the linkage when rebalancing the tree. The only difference is that the `flat_map` is encapsulating the tree implementation and the flat underlying storage, whereas the `intrusive::map` leaves the storage aspect entirely to you. I have an example of a conflation queue [here](https://github.com/mrbald/sandbox/blob/master/feed/conflation.cc) which is using a ring buffer as a storage and an intrusive map as a sorting indexer on top of it.

Ultimately you need to benchmark and compare solutions based on your specific data and usage patterns.